# program to login Facebook using Python requests

Tags: python, facebook

I tried making a script to login Facebook using Python requests. By analyzing the login POST using Firebug, I found that it also sends some other inputs. I used BS4 module to extract values from the login form, prepared a load, and sent it using `requests.session()`. But when I returned the URL, it returned the action link of the form. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated :)

Code:

```
#facebook login
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url='http://www.facebook.com'

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

r=requests.get(url)

soup=bs(r.text,'html.parser')

ft='login_form'

form=soup.find('form',{'id':'login_form'})


inputs=form.find_all('input')

load={}

for i in inputs:
    load[i.get('name')]=i.get('value')

e=input('enter email')

p=input('enter password')

load['email']=e
load['pass']=p
s=requests.session()
r=s.post(form.get('action'),data=load,headers=headers)
print(r.url) #to verify login

s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Facebook needed the cookies along with the input load. I extracted the cookie from the initial get request and passed it along with the post.

Comment: how did u do that ?